# Is $f(z)=$constant considered to be analytic/conformal?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)=$constant is it considered to be analytic/conformal? How does one show this geometrically?

Answer (score 2):

Analytic: yes, since the derivative exists.

Conformal: no, since the derivative is zero everywhere.

Comment: I thought conformal and analytic mappings were equivalent.

Comment: No, an analytic map is conformal at any point where its derivative is nonzero. See here, for example: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConformalMapping.html.